# Using default_scope for multi-tenant app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently in the process of refactoring my Rails app from a single tenant (or no tenant) to a multi-tenant app. After doing lots of research I will now use scopes instead of db schemas, just because I feel more comfortable with it and because I think it is the best solution for my app.

The way to de scoping, as described e.g. [in a Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes), is to use a `tenant_id` column and use a `default_scope` to make sure you only show data related to the current tenant, like this:

```
default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
```

This works fine, but when I look around, I also see a lot of people telling that you shouldn't use default scope, [they are even evil](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil). Instead you should use a normal scope and apply them where necessary. Athough this makes sense and I understand the possible issues you can get with a default scope, it also makes the app more vulnerable, because you can simply forget to apply the scope somewhere.

So I'm still not really convinced wether I should use a default scope or not. So my question is: is it a best practice to use or not use a default scope in Rails 4?

And although I realise this might be an opiniated question, but I'm not looking for a pro/con discussion about default scopes. I am looking for more information if I should use a default scope or not.

Comment: Hi John. Did you use default_scope or normal scope? can you tell me the main reason?

Comment: Hi, I used ``default_scope`` in the end, because it enforces everything to be scoped on ``account`` which is very important to separate the accounts. For all other scopes in my app I would use normal scopes.

Comment: Did you need to create a system administrator, and if so, did default_scope create difficulties?  How did you set it up?

Comment: No difficulties, just make sure you add a tenant_id (or account_id, or any id you use as tenant) in every model which needs to be separated and it will be fine. The default scope I added to a concern, so it wasn't possible to forget to add it to a model.